# CMake: Conflict between a system wide installation of a library and ExternalProject_Add

Tags: cmake, compilation, hdf5

I am currently defining a CMake project where I add the HDF5 library through `ExternalProject_Add`. On a Windows machine I am using, there is a system wide installation of HDF5 on top and when I try to compile, I get a bunch of redefinition errors for the HDF5 headers because VS2019 includes both the headers I added through the `ExternalProject_Add` as well as system wide ones, example:

```
Error   C2365   'H5_ITER_UNKNOWN': redefinition; previous definition was 'enumerator'   C:\somePath C:\<myCmakeBuildDir>\hdf5\src\H5public.h    296
```

It is also followed by a bunch of warning for macro redefinitions which clearly show that the `C:\Program Files\HDF_Group\HDF5\1.12.2\include` is used. I do not call `find_library` or anything else to invoke VS or cmake to search for a systemwide file.

What is the opposite command of `find_library`? I want to avoid compiling with existing local libraries because I want to ensure a very specific version of `hdf5`. I am unsure if this problem is hdf5 specific or if it is a general issue.

Looking forward for your thoughts!

I tried to rename the `ExternalProject_Add` to something different then hdf5 to avoid that naming conflict between the system wide installation and my local project. This did not help.

Comment: `ExternalProject_Add` effectively creates a separate environment for configuring and building the project. It builds the project like you would build it manually. You could try to build HDF5 project as standalone one, and check whether you got the same problems.

Comment: Thanks for the advise! In the moment i uninstall the system wide hdf5 everything compiles good. it seems to be only problematic because that combination of cmake and VS somehow includes the system wide installation alongside the ExternalProject version (without me asking for it). This then causes the double include problem of the header files.